# Database not updating through JSF

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, jsf-2

I am using a JSF to update a database but when I check the database after I push the button, the information isn't there. Am I not connecting correctly? Also, I have 4 buttons, 1 to update the database, 1 to view it, 1 to insert into it, 1 to clear the form. Should these methods be within the information bean or should they all have their own bean? Thank you guys?

index.html

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"

 <h:head>
    <title>Staff Information</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <font size="10"> Staff Information </font>
    <h:form>

        <div style="height:30px">
            <h:outputLabel value="ID:  "/>
            <h:inputText id="ID"
                         value="#{information.ID}"/>
        </div>

        <div style="height:30px">
            <h:outputLabel value="Last Name  " />
            <h:inputText id="lastName"
                         value="#{information.lastName}"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="    First Name  " />
            <h:inputText id="firstName"
                         value="#{information.firstName}"/>

            <h:outputLabel value=" MI  "/>
            <h:inputText id="middle"
                         value="#{information.middle}"/>
        </div>

        <div style="height:30px">
            <h:outputLabel value="Address  "/>
            <h:inputText id="address"
                         value="#{information.address}"/>
        </div>

        <div style="height:30px">
            <h:outputLabel value="City   "/>
            <h:inputText id="city" 
                         value="#{information.city}"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="State  "/>
            <h:inputText id="state" 
                         value="#{information.state}"/>
        </div>

        <div style="height:30px">
            <h:outputLabel value="Telephone # "/>
            <h:inputText id="phone"
                         value="#{information.phone}"/>
        </div>

        <h:commandButton value="View"/> 
        <h:outputText value="&#160;" />

        <h:commandButton value="Insert"/>
        <h:outputText value="&#160;" />

        <h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{information.add()}"/>

        <h:outputText value="&#160;" />

        <h:commandButton type="reset" value="Clear" />
        <h:outputText value="&#160;" />

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

information bean

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "information")
@RequestScoped
public class informationJSFBean {
private Integer id;
private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String middle;
private String address;
private String city;
private String state;
private Long phone;

public informationJSFBean() {
}

public void add(){


    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://local
host:3306/Staff","root","password")

                 String sql = "INSERT INTO Staff(id, lastName, firstName,"
                         + "middle, address, city, state, phone) "
                         + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
                 ps.setLong(1,id);
                 ps.setString(2,lastName);
                 ps.setString(3, firstName);
                 ps.setString(4, middle);
                 ps.setString(5, address);
                 ps.setString(6, city);
                 ps.setString(7, state);
                 ps.setLong(8, phone);

                 int i = ps.executeUpdate(); 
                 System.out.println("Data Added Successfully"); 
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}




public Integer getID(){
    return id;
}
public void setID(Integer id){
    this.id = id;
}
public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getMiddle(){
    return middle;
}
public void setMiddle(String middle){
    this.middle = middle;
}
public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address = address;
}
public String getCity(){
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city){
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState(){
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state){
    this.state = state;
}
public Long getPhone(){
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(Long phone){
    this.phone = phone;
}
public String getResponse(){
    if (lastName == null){
        return "";
}
else{
        return "Thank You, " + firstName + " "
            +lastName + "."+" Your information has been saved. ";
    }
}

}
```

View class

```
public void view(){
    try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     System.out.println("Driver loaded");

     Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
             + "localhost:3306/Staff");
     System.out.println("Database connected");

     String sql = "SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE id="+id;

     System.out.println(sql);

    }
   catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

html for view class

```
<h:commandButton value="View"> 
            <f:param name="action" value="#{information.view()}" />
        </h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Please put in debug and see if it is actually coming and executing your piece where it is inserting data.

Comment: Are you seeing any kind of errors in your server console or browser console?

Comment: @LearningPhase I have no errors.

Comment: Can you confirm your method add is being called via the debugger? Add some system outs at the start of your add method and see is you see the output

Comment: I made a class for the view button with some print statements cuz it seems to be the easiest to debug. I'll add it up top.

Comment: Are you implying that this problem doesn't happen when you run exactly the same JDBC code in a plain Java Application class with `main()` method and some hardcoded variables? I can't for life see how JSF as being a simple HTML form based MVC framework can ever influence behavior of JDBC code after just having provided the needed variables coming from an generated HTML form.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, not a class, a method. It's within my information bean.

Comment: You're not understanding me. JSF is not a database framework. JDBC is a database framework. Problems with database can impossibly be caused by JSF. I was basically asking you to create a plain Java application class with a `main()` method and then hardcode some variables and then execute exactly the same JDBC code there. If that still fails, then you know that your mistake is in JDBC side, not in JSF side. This way you can narrow down the question by removing all irrelevant JSF code and providing that Java application class as a reproducer for anyone trying to reproduce and answer your problem